# Запятые после междометий

Tags: жаргон, пунктуация

Сленговое восклицание "во(,) блин!" Во-первых, является ли тут "во" междометием, во-вторых, нужно ли его отделять запятой?
Спасибо

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Скорее это частица (=вот) и в обособлении не нуждается.
Хотя в разговорно-сниженном стиле грамматика не всегда однозначна, здесь можно спорить.

Answer (score 3):

Междометие ВО существует. Значение "отлично", "здорово". Запятой выделяется.В 7 классе по программе Граник только что рассматривали пример "Во, футбол!" как раз при изучении  темы "Междометие".
Но в Вашем примере ВО по смыслу близко  частице "ВОТ ВЕДЬ". Запятая не нужна.

Answer (score 0):

во блин - междометное сочетание, без запятой